# pgadmin4 connection timed out when connecting with remote database

Tags: postgresql, centos7, psql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect the postgres Database on Remote Server but I am failed to do so . I have tried every single solution nothing worked out.

this is the problem i am facing [image]

I have tried following steps

1. Configuration of pg_hba.conf

   ```
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32             md5
   host    all             all             0.0.0.0/32            md5
   ```
2. postgressql.conf

   ```
        listen_addresses = '*'
   ```
3. ```
        sudo service postgresql restart
   ```
4. Defining the inbound rules for port 5432 incase firewall block but I have already off the firewall

**5) turn off the firewall**

6. telnet <host_IP> <port_number>

**I got unable to connect with host IP**

7. psql -h hostip -U dbuser -d dbname

when i use the above line i was successfully connected with ssh putty

but I am failed to connect from PG Admin

- Any help would be appreciated

**the database default port is 5432 on the server i have checked twice and its working fine on that**

Server Configuration

```
Postgres installed version is 9.4.
Server operating system : Centos 7
Pgadmin 4 on windows
```

Comment: The fact that you got unable to connect from the telnet step means it's a network issue; you can't reach that IP on that port from the computer where you're running pgadmin4. You don't specify how you're using putty, but if you're SSHing into some other server where psql then works, that implies that the machine you are SSHing into can reach it. You can look into port forwarding so that the pgadmin4 connection goes via the box you're SSHing into, but it's been many years since I've used windows/putty so I'm afriad I don't know specifics.

Comment: @AdamKG I am have also tried with the DataGrid software but I am getting the same error connection timed out

Comment: @AdamKG Any Solution will help me alot